# strings in hebrew in python for s60

Tags: python, unicode, string, hebrew, pys60

I'm using python for S60.
I want to use string in hebrew, to represent them on the GUI and to send them in SMS message.
It seems that the PythonScriptShell don't accept such expressions, for example:

```
u"אבגדה"
```

what can I do?
thanks

**development of situation:**
I added the line:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

as the first line in the source file and in notepad++ I selected: Encoding>>Convert to utf8.

now, the GUI appears in Hebrew but when I selected an option the selection value cannot be compared to a string in Hebrew in the code (probably) and there is no response.

On PythonScriptShell appears the warning:

Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal.

Help me, please.

Comment: >don't accept such expressions -- could you explain what do you mean? If it gives you an error, please post the traceback.

Comment: the error message on the shell screen:

"SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe1' in file ... on line ... but no encoding

Comment: Oh, so you have `u"אבגדה"` in the source file? Or are you entering in the interactive shell?

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this in both bluetooth and on-phone consoles with PyS60 2.0, and non-ASCII unicode was handled w/out exceptions.

If you have that string in the file rather than passing it in the console, error is caused by lack of encoding specification in the file.

Add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` as first line there.

Comment: I added this row exactly and got the error message:

"UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode bytesin position 0-2: invalid data.

Comment: @Day_Dreaner ー then, obviously, you need to save your file in utf-8, or edit the header to match w/e encoding your editor uses.

Comment: how do I save a file in utf-8? I'm using npp.

Answer (score 0):

convert your words to unicode characters using
[unichr](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#unichr)
eg unichr(1507) for char ף

refer to the decimal values in this table: http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~tomw/java/unicode.html#x0590

Comment: I didn't understand. I have a string in hebrew, what to do next?

Comment: I don't think that makes a huge difference compared to a Unicode literal like `u"אבגדה"`: Both result in Python Unicode strings. The problem must be on the S60 side.

Answer (score 0):

Add up
ru = lambda txt: str(txt).decode('utf-8','ignore')

And add the function before each text use
ru("אבגדה")